# Japanese text in Symfony form titles

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm working on a project that requires using the Symfony form component, and I need to be able to add kanji for some of the field names. Using English this works just fine:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('name', TextType::class)
->add('price', TextType::class)
->getForm();
```

When I try to name any of the fields in Japanese though, I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The name "名" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").
```

Is there a way to change just the display name of a field?

Comment: Use a [label](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#label) instead of relying on the field name to be human-readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('name', TextType::class, [
    'label' => '名',
])->...
```

This should do the job, and or could use the resource file if you would like to avoid including language specific characters.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('name', TextType::class, [
    'label' => form1.name,
])->...
```

inside your translation resource file(e.g. Resources/tranlations/labels.ja.yml) add the content

```
form1.name: "名"
```